# Equivalence of limits, Spivak Chapter 5 Number 10b -- $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x-a)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Good day,

I want to apologize because I made this post wrong last time. I am going to ask you again. I hope this time will be better.

I am trying to solve an exercise from the Spivak book, but I think there's an error in the theorem.

We are asked to prove the following:

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x-a)$

To test the theorem I take two examples:

**First:** $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=2$

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} x^2=4$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x-a)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (x-2)^2=4$

Perfect, this work for this function.

**Second:** $f(x)=x^3$ and $a=2$

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} x^3=8$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x-a)$ $\iff$ $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} (x-2)^3=-8$

So in the second example the theorem is not true, and I think there is an error in the book.

Could anyone tell me if there is an error in the analysis I made?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have made the post wrong this time as well.

Comment: Imagine if everyone made a title like yours. It'd be really difficult to find things!

Comment: What problem is it in Spivak? Are there other pre-requisites on $f$? Can you type the complete problem?

Comment: I have changed the title to your comfort

Comment: @JulianTorres I don't see that problem as $10b$ in the version of Spivak I found online but problem $9$ uses $l$ instead of $a$ and has it outside the function, i.e. $f(x)-a$, not $f(x-a)$.

See problem $9$ of chapter $5$ of https://ia801906.us.archive.org/29/items/Calculus_643/Spivak-Calculus.pdf

Comment: @JohnDouma I have reviewed the Spivak edition you just published here and it turns out you are rigth, my Spivak edition is diferent in just that exercise, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $f(x+a)$.  You are right, you found a counterexample in the other case.  You could have used $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Thanks for your help